# DbConfigurationTypeAttribute in code vs. codeConfigurationType in web.config

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

We're working on an EF6 application, that uses a custom DbConfiguration class.  Up til now, we've been configuring system to use our DbConfiguration, rather than creating a default, by decorating each DbContext class with a DbConfigurationTypeAttribute.

We installed an instance on our QA site, today, and were getting HTTP 500 errors. After turning off CustomErrors, so we could see the detail, we saw:

> An instance of 'DbConfigurator' must be set at application start 
>   before using any Entity Framework features or must be registered in
>   the application's config file.

This confused me, because according to Microsoft, the DbConfigurationTypeAttributes should have worked:

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699#Moving

And they did work, on our Development machines. And I am absolutely certain that each of our DbContext objects is so decorated.

Not knowing what else to do, I added the codeConfigurationType attribute to the entityFramework element in the web.config and everything ran fine.

I then tried removing the DbConfigurationTypeAttributes from the code, thinking that defining this in multiple places was a bad idea.  And all my unit tests proceeded to fail - they don't access the web.config. That part, at least, makes sense.

The rest of it, though, confuses me. Why do the DbConfigurationTypeAttributes not work, when running in IIS7?